How many Married Bishops at Nicea?
Do we have any indication from original sources, or secondary sources, how many of the Bishops who participated at Nicaea I were married?

I'm not sure why this question is receiving downvotes; this is a perfectly legitimate and well-formatted question.

How many Married Bishops at Nicea?
We can only guess at the answer and it would seem that the percentage of married bishops over unmarried bishops was probably quite small.
With between 250 and 300 bishops in attendance, we only know the names of a handful of bishops. Eusebius speaks of more than 250 bishops.

Most of the bishops present were Greeks; among the Latins we know only Hosius of Cordova, Cecilian of Carthage, Mark of Calabria, Nicasius of Dijon, Donnus of Stridon in Pannonia, and the two Roman priests, Victor and Vincentius, representing the pope. - The First Council of Nicaea

A leading participant in the Council, Eusebius of Caesarea, wrote: "It is fitting that those in the priesthood and occupied in the service of God, should abstain after ordination from the intercourse of marriage." This would seem, in some degree, indicate the vast majority of bishops and priests at this time in history would have been celibate.

"indicate the vast majority of bishops and priests at this time in history would have been celibate." don't conflate celibacy with the state of continence. Clerical continence was required from the 2nd century; celibacy came later for all clergy.
